# When should one use EPEL 5 or EPEL 6?

Tags: centos, yum, repository, epel

I am not familiar with repos, and I don't get *why* there are several versions of EPEL (this is a bit philosophical I know, but I am afraid I am missing something in all that).

Should I just look inside of them which one has the packages I want, with no other consideration?

(using CentOS 5.x)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- EPEL 5 is meant to align with RHEL5, CentOS 5, Scientific Linux 5.x, etc.
- EPEL 6 is meant to align with RHEL6, CentOS 6, Scientific Linux 6.x, etc.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F

*If you are running an EL6 version, please visit here to get the newest 'epel-release' package for EL6: The newest version of 'epel-release' for EL6*

*If you are running an EL5 version, please visit here to get the newest 'epel-release' package for EL5: The newest version of 'epel-release' for EL5*

Comment: Great, didn't know what "EL" meant. Thanks